# Clearing text field on Modal Popup using Angular JS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have button on my page which opens a modal dialog having a text field on it. I am opening Modal dialog for the first time and putting some text in the text field and closing it. When I am reopening the modal dialog, text field content remains as it was. I want to get empty text field every time.

EDIT:

My textbox is on Div which is displayed as a Modal dialog. Also that textbox is not getting focus when modal dialog is opened. Below is my code.

```js
$scope.OpenModal = function() {
  //Popup the Modal Dialog Box
  $scope.modalTitle = "Confirm?";
  $scope.note=null;
  $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  $scope.itemDesc="";
  $scope.focusInput=true;
  
  $scope.ok = function () {
   $scope.Message = "Confirmed";
   $scope.modalShown = false;
   $scope.focusInput = true;
  }
  
  $scope.cancel = function () {
   $scope.Message = "Cancelled";
   $scope.modalShown = false;
   $scope.focusInput = true;
  }
}

app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close close' ng-click='hideModal()'>x</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
  };
});

app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
   return {
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
       scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
         console.log('value=',value);
         
         if(value === true) { 
           $timeout(function() {
             element[0].focus(); 
           }, 20);
         }
       });
       element.bind('blur', function() {
         console.log('blur')
         scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
       })
     }
   };
});
```

```html
<button ng-click="OpenModal()" ng-disabled="isValid"
 role="button" >
<span class="fa fa-ban"></span> Open
</button>
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='440px'>
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
     <p>{{modalMessage}} </p>
<input type="text" focus-me="focusInput" id="txtDesc" ng-model="itemDesc" />
    </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button ng-click="ok()" focus-me="true" >OK</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
 </div>
</modal-dialog>
```

Comment: put your code here so we can help better

Comment: If you have modal object variable, you should just reset it on modal open/close.
`$scope.modal = {};`

Comment: Do you mean to say like this? `<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='440px' id="myModal" ng-model="modal">`

Comment: @AjinkyaJagtap: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I can suggest you should clear the text field of the modal while closing the modal.

From your angular code, you may clear it very easily, lets say it is $scope.modalText,

```
 $scope.modalText = "";
```

Just add this line in the function which is getting called on the click of close modal. If it doesn't resolve the issue, please share your code.

Update: Update your cancel function with the below code. I have just added the code to clear the text box

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
                $scope.Message = "Cancelled";
                $scope.modalShown = false;
                $scope.focusInput = true;
                $scope.txtDesc = "";
            }
```

Comment: When I am closing the modal popup and reopening it, binding with textbox is getting lost.

Comment: I have shared my almost complete code in my question above.